# How to get specific data from ROOM database when an item is selected in Spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a student entity it contains, student name, student mobile number. I am adding student record using the student name, I am selecting student name from a spinner  while adding new record. so my question is when I select student name, I want to get the mobile number of that specific student in textview below my spinner.

This is how I am getting all names in the spinner

```
 private void loadSpinnerData() {
        studentViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(StudentViewModel.class);
        studentViewModel.getAllStudents().observe(this, new Observer<List<Student>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Student> students) {
                String[] nameLists = new String[students.size()];
                for (i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
                    nameLists[i] = students.get(i).getStudentName() + " " + students.get(i).getStudentFatherName() +
                            " " + students.get(i).getStudentSurname();
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> studentNames = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, nameLists);
                studentNames.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                selectStudentName.setAdapter(studentNames);
            }
        });

    }
```

This is my spinner adapter

```
selectStudentName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {
                if ( position == -1 ) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddRecord.this, "No record is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(AddRecord.this, name + " is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   for (int i = 0; i < adapterView.getCount(); i++ ){

                   }
                }
            }
```

How do I get mobile number of the selected student name ? Thank you !

Comment: This is how I did it and works like a charm

Comment: `String item_position = String.valueOf(position);
                    final int mobile = Integer.valueOf(item_position);
                 
                    studentViewModel.getAllStudents().observe(AddRecord.this, new Observer<List<Student>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(List<Student> students) {
                            String[] mobileList = new String [students.size()];
                            mobileList[mobile] = students.get(mobile).getMobileNumber();
                            studentMOB.setText(mobileList[mobile]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple dear, just use your view model class object(studentViewModel) to get live data instance like this-

```java
selectStudentName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {
                if ( position == -1 ) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddRecord.this, "No record is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    String studentMobileNumber = studentViewModel.getAllStudents().getValue().get(position).getMobileNumber()

                }
            }
```